# Require proxy when updating an entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

The situation is, when I try to update an entity that with `many to one` relation with another, it throws a warning that says the proxy doesn't exists. Because I didn't generate the proxy, so it cannot find. But the question is, does it need the proxy all the time?
Here is my code.

```
class UmMemberSectionInfo extends \DoctrineHelper {
    // define the fields that is char dependent.
    public static $CHAR_DEPENDENT = array('name');

    /**
     * @var \UmMemberSection
     *
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="UmMemberSection")
     * @JoinColumns({
     *   @JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $member;
}

class UmMemberSection extends \DoctrineHelper {
    /**
     * var \UmMemberSectionInfo
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UmMemberSectionInfo",mappedBy="member")
     */
    protected $info;
}
```

When I use `merge()` of `EntityManager` for instance of `UmMemberSectionInfo` it throws
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `C:\php_projects\wcms\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 92`

```
15  0.3056  16012680    Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->createEntity( )    ..\SimpleObjectHydrator.php:135
16  0.3058  16015544    Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory->getProxy( )    ..\UnitOfWork.php:2591
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in doctrine, proxy is the must if using relational database, or you can keep your relationship not over then one level.

For example:

1.`Member` is `OneToMany` of `Book`.

2.`Book` is `ManyToOne` of `Member`

3.`BookComment` is `ManyToOne` of `Book`

The you have:

1. Getting book from `Member` doesn't need proxy.
2. Getting `Member` From `BookComment` needs proxy.

I think it's because doctrine needs to avoid infinity getting relations from database. So if the relationship link is larger then one level, doctrine determine to use lazy loading.